# What is the use of the [BOOT]/Bootable_NoEmulation.img file on several boot images?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, iso-image, mbr

I've seen a file called `[BOOT]/Bootable_NoEmulation.img` on several boot images, and always wondered what it's use is. Neither found a suitable magic number nor could Google help me so I ask here.

It's 2048 bytes large but only the first 560 bytes are filled, the rest is full of zeros - except for the footer.

What's the use of it, seems to me some kind of a placeholder or workaround to comply with some RFCs or other standards.

I just pasted a hexdump [here](http://pastebin.com/zMywRnwb).

Comment: If your image is CD/DVD, that is the floppy emulation image for the BIOS to boot the disc. Don't have further technical information, though.